# What is the difference between copy and xcopy command?

Tags: command-prompt, dos

I need to know what is the precise difference between these 2 commands ?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quoting from the result of `copy /?`

> Copies one or more than one files to another location.

Quoting from the result of `xcopy /?`

> Copies files and directory trees.

The essential difference between the two commands is that when you provide the path of a folder to `copy`, only the **files in that folder** will be copied to the specified destination.

Providing the path of a folder to `xcopy` will copy **the folder itself** along with its contents (subject to flags used with the command) to the specified destination.

Comment: xcopy will not copy the subdirectories unless you add /e or /s to the command.

Answer (score 1):

Another difference I experienced, with W10 batch command copy didn't copy a file to OneDrive and xcopy did. Don't know why, it just worked.